# Trying to extract a list from a web page using selenium driver with Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, selenium

I am trying to extract a list stored in a web page using Selenium Driver and Python.

The List is stored as

```
    ol class="My_Favorite_food"
        a href="/recipes/cuisine"
            li
                span style="margin-left: 10px;"South Indian 
                    span style="margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 5px; font-weight: 400;"Tomato Rice/span 
                    span style="font-size: 0.8em;"(TC)/span span style="float: right; margin-right: 10px;"60/span
                /span
            /li
        /a
    /ol
```

I have tried using the 'find_elements_by_xpath" with little success. Where am I going wrong? I want to extract "South Indian", "Tomato Rice", 60

```
try:
    dropdown_list = br.find_elements_by_xpath('.//ol[@class="My_Favorite_food"]/a[@href="/recipes"]/li')
    items = dropdown_list.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
    for item in items:
        Print ("Item text: >%s<>" % item.text)
except:
    print("That record is not found")

return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
items = dropdown_list.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
```

tries to search for 'li' items within your 'li' tag.
Changing it to

```
items = dropdown_list.find_elements_by_tag_name("span")
```

should do the trick.